# How to update tables from a View using Linq to Entities

Tags: view, linq-to-entities

I have a View in an SQL Server Database, which involves many different tables. I am using Linq to Entities to access the database, so I have no problem getting and showing view's result.

But the problem is when I want to modify some field in those results. As long as a view doesn't have a primary key, the Entity is read-only, so the question is:

Is there any way to modify the object with the view's data and save those changes in the corresponding tables?

Sorry for my english, but it's not my native language.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some requirements for VIEW to be updatable. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx). You say your view references many tables, so you have to implement `INSTEAD OF` trigger.