# Saving entities from view

Tags: c#, view, entity

in the entity framework, I have a view, which includes two tables. I'm interested in updating a table from this view. I found this question:
[How to update tables from a View using Linq to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509490/how-to-update-tables-from-a-view-using-linq-to-entities)

Since this doesnt seem to be that easy, is there a good alternative solution?
The only solution I can see is filling the properties from the view one to one to the object in the table, but I'm pretty sure, this cant be the answer.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of code?

Comment: Hello there,

I made it simply for this solutation, since I have to update only one property. But now I have another strange happening:

                        `tmpTel.StartTracking();
                        tmpTel.TELECOM_NO = vTel.TELECOM_NO;

                        //Klappt 
                        ctx.TELECOMs.ApplyChanges(tmpTel);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                        result += ctx.SaveChanges(System.Data.Objects.SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);`

Here is the funny part: When I execute SaveChanges() (without options) it works, with options it doesnt.